# Batch File returning folder size and delete content if greater than 50gb

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory

I am trying to write a batch script, which will first return the sum of multiple folder locations and if these are greater than 50GB, delete the content.

I was googling around and still don't know how to return the size of a folder (in GB).

Can anyone help`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of a folder can be derived by `dir /S` (see the summary at the very bottom of the output, which contains the total amount of bytes occupied by all sub-items). This can be extracted like this:

```cmd
set "PREVB="
for /F "skip=2 tokens=3" %%B in ('
    dir /S /-C "\path\to\folder"
') do (
    call set "BYTES=%%PREVB%%"
    set "PREVB=%%B"
)
```

But be careful: do not treat this number as an integer (by `set /A` or `if  EQU`/`GTR`/...), because `cmd` supports signed 32-bit integers only, which is easily exceeded by folder sizes.

To check against 50 GB you might split the resulting number, like:

```cmd
rem // Split huge number into GB and ones:
set "BYTES_GIGA=%BYTES:~,-9%"
set "BYTES_ONES=%BYTES:~-9%"
rem // Ensure GB part to be non-empty:
if not defined BYTES_GIGA set "BYTES_GIGA=0"
rem // Remove leading zeroes from ones:
set /A "BYTES_ONES=1%BYTES_ONES%%%1000000000"
```

Then you can round the GB number up, if you wish:

```cmd
if %BYTES_ONES% GTR 0 set /A "BYTES_GIGA+=1"
```

Finally, check the GB number whether or not it exceeds the predefined limit:

```cmd
if %BYTES_GIGA% GTR 50 (
    rem // Do something, perhaps delete the entire folder:
    rmdir /S /Q "\path\to\folder"
)
```

Comment: Hi, this works good, but only for one folder. As soon as I duplicate the code and paste another folder inside, the code will stop working.
How to I get to check multiple folders?

Comment: This is just intended to show you how you can derive the size of a single folder, but not to provide a fully working script, that is why it accepts a single folder only. To execute that in a loop or something, you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for all variables that are written *and* read within that loop...

Comment: Sorry I am quite new to this, how do I manage these Expansions?

Comment: How do you specify the directories you want to determine the sizes of? by a text file?

Comment: I use '    dir /S /-C "%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Temp\Adobe\After Effects" ' to specify my directory. It works the firast time but as soon as I duplicate the code to check another folder path it will simply stop working.

Comment: "...it will simply stop working" is not a quite precise description of what is happening. Note that `%HOMEDRIVE%` does not contain the drive, so specify `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` instead...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that `dir /s /-c` returns a final block:

```
Total Files Listed:
         51 File(s)       88492332 bytes
         14 Dir(s)    112224022528 bytes free
```

And you just need to parse out that value (`88492332`).

***Can you provide more explicit detail about what code you have, and why it isn't working?***

---

This works for me:

**GetSize.bat**

```
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('dir /-c /s ^| findstr /N /C:"Total Files Listed"') do set SKIP=%%a
for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('dir /-c /s ^| more +%SKIP%') do (set FOLDER_SIZE=%%a & goto :end)

:end
echo Final Folder Size is %FOLDER_SIZE%
```

Answer (score 0):

with robocoby Output and erase

The code was reworked.

```
@echo off
setlocal
prompt $g$s

 rem set size= 150.0 m
 rem usage -> see SUB :Fsize
set size= 50.0 g

call :createTMP
set /a _N=0

:Listing
 rem list Folder List size and delete
for /D %%F in (
  D:\1?
  D:\80
  D:\2014-*
  D:\a

) do (
  if exist %%F if /i NOT "%~0"==":Listing" (
    set /a _N+=1
    call mklink /j "%%empty.link.tmp%%\%%_N%%" "%%~F"
  ) else call :delall "%%~F"
)

 rem --- END SETTINGS ---


if :SUB==only (
 :createTMP
 set "empty.tmp=%temp%\empty_%time::=%"
 set "empty.link.tmp=%temp%\link_%time::=%"
 md "%empty.tmp%"
 md "%empty.link.tmp%"
 exit /b
)

if /i "%~0"==":Listing" (
  :deltmp
  for /d %%D in (
    "%empty.link.tmp%\*"
    "%empty.link.tmp%"
    "%empty.tmp%" 
  ) do rd "%%~D"
  exit /b
)

:Listsize  
call :Fsize "%size%" size.max
for /f "skip=2tokens=6*" %%a in ('
   robocopy /L /purge /njh "%empty.tmp%" "%empty.link.tmp%" /nfl /ndl ^|find " 0 "
') do call :Fsize "%%b" size.out deci.mal pre
if NOT %size.out% lss %size.max% (
  echo Folders: %deci.mal% %pre% ^> %size%
  call :Listing
)else echo Folders %deci.mal% %pre% ^< %size% &call :deltmp
exit/b

:Fsize "512.0 k" [VAR1-floating point [VAR2-to display only [VAR3-prefix]]]
 rem to use with output of robocopy 
 rem set with decimal minimum 1/1     max b  =1024
 rem set with decimal minimum 1/10    max k  =.9    rounded + 102.3  bytes (+  10 %)
 rem          decimal minimum 1/100   max m  =.99   rounded + 10.23  KiB   (+   1 %)
 rem          decimal minimum 1/1000  max g  =.999  rounded + 1.023  MiB   (+ 0,1 %)
 rem 500.0 b        -> 500      bytes
 rem 200.5 k        -> 200,5    KiB
 rem 350.04 m       -> 350,04   MiB
 rem 1.001 g        -> 1,001    GiB
 rem VAR1 size.out  - Binary prefix and number to floating point
 rem VAR2 deci.mal  - Reverse the calculation part to display only
 rem VAR3 pre.fix   - Reverse the calculation to add prefix
set/a p=-1,TC=10000
for %%N in (b k m g t p)Do set /a "p+=1,%%N=p"
for /f "tokens=1-3delims=. " %%A in ("%~1 0 b")Do (
  set/a"pre.fix=TC*(%%C+1) + %%A"
  set "deci.mal=%%A.%%B"
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  set "FS=!pre.fix!.%%B"
  for /f "tokens=1,2" %%S in  ("!FS! !deci.mal!")Do (
    endlocal
    if NOT "%~2"=="" (set "%~2=%%S")else set "size.out=%%S"
    if NOT "%~3"=="" set "%~3=%%T"
  )
)
set/ax=pre.fix/TC-1
for %%s in (b k m g t p)Do 2>nul set/a"N/=(%%s-x)"||^
 if NOT "%~4"=="" (set "%~4=%%s")else set "pre.fix=%%s"

exit /b

:delall
 rem be carfully - this will erase all Data !
 rem 1st with option /L only list this Files
 rem without /L will erase all Data 
:@echo off
setlocal
set "T=%temp%\DF%time::=%"
md "%T%" ||exit /b 1
:Delete
if "%~1" equ "" goto :end
robocopy /L /fp /purge /ns /np /njh /njs "%T%" "%~dp1\" "%~nx1"
shift
goto :Delete
:end
rd "%T%"
exit /b 0
```

[robocopy](/questions/tagged/robocopy) [size](/questions/tagged/size) [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) [del](/questions/tagged/del)

Comment: @max07 How to I get to check multiple folders?

Comment: You can collect in a seperate Folder with `mklink /j D:\linkedFolder D:\seperate\#1` all multiple Folders.

Comment: @max07 Works also volume-spreading.
An NTFS volume must exist to create the links.

Comment: I tried this and it instantly quits. Cant get this working.

Comment: What error message is output when you start the batch in the command prompt?